# `alter table if exists` raises an error on Amazon RDS Postgresql 15.2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

On most instances of Postgres I've tried, this query works just fine if `my_table` does not exist:

```
alter table if exists public.my_table add column foo boolean;
NOTICE:  relation "my_table" does not exist, skipping
ALTER TABLE
```

I've tried on multiple Postgres versions, including `15.2`.

However, on AWS RDS specifically, their `15.2` version will raise an error if the table does not exist:

```
=> alter table if exists public.my_table add column foo boolean;
ERROR:  relation "public.my_table" does not exist
```

This does not appear to be an issue with other versions of RDS Postgres.

Any idea why this might be happening? Is there a parameter that's flipped on in 15.2 by default that causes this to happen?

Comment: Hello I have ther same behavior between RDS version 13.7 and 13.10...

Comment: I've just spent 3 days chasing down this error, I can confirm that it is present in RDS with Postgres 11.19.

Answer (score 3):

Hello I have opened a support ticket with AWS, and confirmed this behavior is known for minor version 11.19, 12.14, 13.10 and 14.7 and was corrected in the next minor versions : 11.20, 12.15, 13.11 and 14.8.

Comment: Is there public documentation where it shows the bug is fixed? I am having the same issue in 13.11

Comment: It happens for us with 14.8, seems it's not fixed yet.